# Why the typescript narrowing seems doesn't work with default value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

why in TestErr function does the variable testvar inside the if-else block give the type string | number?

Seems it works only without default value. But the variant seems correct in both cases.

[typescriptlang demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=35&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUBuBDATgSywDtgB%20ALigCIBGSqAHyoCZKBuNKYCAZ2GxwqEArgFsARhBzsAvihShIUAEIJkHfgWIVKATh2UOXXvwq98hAOYy5C6ABUewAAo4A9mG6qUjGN%20VyAMyFCAGNgPFdCKAdeAFEcHAAKJA0iYFUaSgAaTkd%20aQoY5zcPAEo1dDwAqETU4gR4RF19ctR0Sura3E10xqbaVul0AHphqEk3HCgsTwgAD0gwiAATKA50Iz5cVihR3ONcU2BzCwYoYXFJDiGIABtuaDb2qq78NIamvUpB3bGJ1ymM3GCwgS1W632Wykv0hJigZjwljOFwkOGuhjy2xhmzhCKRjBRV1kKCCoXCkWijgA8gBrZJ1YA5HG4AqU3gudzcVocKo1BkfKhfbntKC8149AWZH4w-6A2YgsFrEXM6F7FVHE7Xcb3R4Ql78vqClrIIZ7WXTeWLLjg5WY1VjdXw46IizojZ2nZqu0al3I0SolDSIA)

```
type A = {
  variant?: "1" | "2";
  testvar: number;
}

type B = {
  variant: "99"
  testvar: string;
}

type TestProps = 
| A
| B

function TestErr({variant = "1", testvar}: TestProps) {
  if (variant === "99") {
    if (variant === "1") {}  // error as expected 
    testvar; // testvar: string | number
  } else {
    if(variant === "99") {} // error as expected 
    testvar; // testvar: string | number
  }
  testvar; // testvar: string | number
}

function TestOk({variant, testvar}: TestProps) {
  if (variant === "99") {
    if (variant === "1") {}  // error as expected 
    testvar; // testvar: string
  } else {
    if(variant === "99") {} // error as expected 
    testvar; // testvar: string
  }
  testvar; // testvar: string | number
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assign the default value of `1` to `variant` in `TestErr`, in this way TS can not discriminate the types.

You can see that in `TestOk`, `variant` is of type `"1" | "2" | "99" | undefined"` that is correct since `variant` in `type A` could be `undefined`.

But, because you assign a default value to `variant` in `TesErr`, now the type become `"1" | "2" | "99"` which is not what we are expecting from `TestProps`.